# SSIS using square brackets as text qualifiers

Tags: ssis

We are trying to solve this problem and can’t come to a solution.

We are loading a csv file.

Given:

Test, 1, [Bobby, said "What happened"]

We chose the “[]” as the Text Qualifier so it would not clash with the internal double quotes. But it appears that you can only use one qualifier “[", so it will not identify the other "]“, do you have any suggestions on how we should handle this?

PS could change the text qualifier for something else if it would make it better.

Comment: I like to use pipe characters for text qualifiers.

Comment: What if you made your text qualifier a pipe `|` or a tilde `~` or something else that shouldn't show up in your text?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Derived column transformation to extract anything between [ and ]. This certainly makes the assumption that there wont be any intermediate [ and ].